# Derivative of result with repect to its function

Tags: derivatives, neural-networks

I'm trying to implement the simplest form of backpropagation. The backpropagation is a widely used in Neural Networks algorithm; the steps are, basically: Ⅰ) calculating the result of a formula with a variable called "weight" *(the forward pass)*, next Ⅱ) finding the difference between the actual result, and the wanted one, then Ⅲ) finding the derivative of the difference with respect to the "weight" *(to see how much it affected the miss)*, and Ⅳ) adding *(or subtracting)* the derivative result to the weight.

So, let $f(x,w) = (x+w)^2$, x is an input, and w is a weight. Let $f(3,5) = 64$. Now, suppose with the same $x$ we want the result $80$ instead, so let $E = 80-64 = 16$, then calculate $\frac{dE}{dw}$.

This is the step where I'm stuck. The derivative of the $(x+w)^2$ is $2x+2w$, but I don't understand where am I supposed to substitute the E. Perhaps am I calculating the wrong derivative? I mean, that $\frac{df}{dw}=\frac{df}{dx}=2x+2w$, but probably $\frac{dE}{dw}≠2x+2w$? I have no idea where to go further ☹

Comment: Is $E=f(x,w)$? I'm sorry, I don't think I quite understand your notation

Comment: @zz20s $E$ is the difference between the actual result and the wanted one, i.e. $E = 80 - 64 = 16$.

Comment: What is the function for the wanted value?

Comment: @zz20s it is $f(x,w) = (x + w)^2$. I want that function to return $80$ instead of $64$ with the same $x$, i.e. by modifying the $w$ instead. In ANN it is achieved by finding the derivative of the difference with respect to $w$, and adding that derivative to $w$, it is called «backpropagation».

Comment: @zz20s to be clear — I'm trying to fully understand backpropagation by implementing its simplest form, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: @zz20s In neural networks the function is actually a function of many $w$s, like $f(x,w_1,w_2,…,w_n)$, and in the backpropagation step one is finding derivatives with respect to every $w$, i.e. $\frac{dE}{dw_1}$, $\frac{dE}{dw_2}$, …, $\frac{dE}{dw_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are implementing what is essentially Newton's method (gradient descent):

$E = f(x,w) \approx f(x,w_0) + \frac{\partial f(x,w)}{\partial E}|_{w_0} \times \delta w$. If you put $E = 80$ and $f(x,w_0)=64$ then in the next iteration replace $w_0$ by $w_0 + \delta w$.

Comment: Okay, I think your answer is the right one, just wait a bit for me to calculate, I'm not that good in math as I wanted to be. What does mean vertical bar in your formula? Unless it is «absolute value» or «set builder notation» *(neither of which does it seem to be)*, I've never met other usage of vertical bar in algebraic formulas. Also, is $δw$ with the example formula supposed to be $2w$?

Comment: Okay, since the period is expiring, and I have to award someone a bounty, I'll give it to you; but I won't yet accept the answer as I want from you a bit elaboration.

Comment: Not keen on accepting something as "default"!

Comment: I didn't want to, the problem is that the expired points won't be returned, so I can't wait for improvement, and then award them. At least your mention of gradient descent gave me a hint for where to go further.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, with $E = 16$, it wouldn't be mathematical sense to compute: $$\frac {dE}{dw} (x + w)^2$$ as a derivative because if you substitute $16$ for $E$, you would get: $$\frac {16x^2}{w} + 32x^2 + 16w$$ Since you are working with a multivariable function, you can use the multivariable chain rule.

### Multivariable Chain Rule

Let $z = f(x, w)$. Since $f(x, w) = (x + w)^2$, $z = (x + w)^2$. Before we do anything, we'll expand $(x + w)^2$ to get $x^2 + 2xw + w^2$. Now, we will use the following formula: $$dz(x, w) = \frac {\partial z}{\partial x}dx  + \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}dw$$ for $z = f(x, w)$. When we calculate the partial derivative with respect to $x$, we get $2w + 2x$. When we calculate with respect to $w$, we get $2w + 2x$ (which is the same answer as the last partial derivative). So, we have $$dz=(2w + 2x)dx + (2w + 2x)dw = 2w + 2x \ dx + 2w + 2x \ dw$$ We can factor out a 2 to get: $$2(x \ dx + w \ dw)$$ So, your final answer is $2(x \ dx + w \ dw)$.